# Tengo un listview que filtro con un spinner, y me gustaria de ese resultado filtrarlo con un edittext

Tags: listview, spinner, edittext

Tengo un Listview que contiene informacion de una base de datos Sqlite, y esta informacion puedo filtrarla por la familia de los productos con un spinner, hasta aqui todo bien, pero necesito poner un buscador para hacer mas expedita la busqueda ( por eso queria colocar un editext que fuera filtrando )

Atento a sus comentarios
Carlos

[image: aqui adjunto una imagen de lo que tengo actualmente]

Comment: Hola, podrías ser un poco mas preciso en tu pregunta, te recomiendo visitar [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas de parte de la comunidad una buena respuesta a tu pregunta.

Comment: ahi hice una mejor redacción y adjunte una imagen